# Clarification regarding CVE-2020-25717

Tags: vulnerability, centos, samba

We use CentOS 7 and have only samba-client in our deployment.
(We do not have samba server in our deployment.)

Does the [CVE-2020-25717](https://www.samba.org/samba/security/CVE-2020-25717.html) affect our deployment?

Comment: Patched @ November 9, 2021. So, unless you have not updated your system since then, you should be fine.

Comment: @pLumo not clear. Does the CVE-2020-25717 affect deployments without the samba server if we do not patch it?
It is obvious that if we patch the deployment it is resolved

Comment: @schroeder, why was my question migrated to this area? No one reads and answers questions here ...

Comment: You should check [On-Topic](https://security.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) section of Security SE.

Comment: Because it is more about Samba than it is about security or the CVE.

Comment: And since your link is about the configuration of the Samba server, and all patches are for the server, it seems rather obvious that the clients are out of scope. So, it is here to help explain the difference between the server and client.